# What events (.net, WMI, etc.) can I hook to take an action when a PowerShell module is imported?

Tags: powershell

I want to create a listener in PowerShell that can take an action when an arbitrary PowerShell module is imported.

Is there any .net event or WMI event that is triggered during module import (manually or automatically) that I can hook and then take an action if the module being imported matches some criteria?

---

Things that I have found so far that might be components of a solution

- [Module event logging](https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2016/02/greater_visibilityt.html)
- [Runspace pool state changed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspacepool.statechanged?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#applies-to)
- [Triggering PowerShell when event log entry is created](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2011/08/25/trigger-a-powershell-script-from-a-windows-event/)

  - Maybe not directly useful but if we could hook the same event from within a running PowerShell process that might help
- [Use PowerShell profile](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/persistent-powershell-the-powershell-profile/) to load PowerShellConfiguration module
- Create a [proxy function](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/New-ProxyCommand-a-simple-9735745e) for Import-Module to check whether the module being imported matches one that needs configuration loaded for it

  - In testing Import-Module isn't called when auto loading imports a module so this doesn't catch every imported module

---

**Context**

I want to push the limits of aspect oriented programming/separation of concerns/DRY in PowerShell where things like module state (API keys, API root URLs, credentials, database connection strings, etc.) can all be set via set functions that only change the state of in memory module scoped internal variables so that an external system can pull those values from any arbitrary means of persistence (psd1, PSCustomObject, registry, environment variables, json, yaml, database query, etcd, web service call, anything else that is appropriate to your specific environment).

The problem keeps coming up in the modules we write and is made even more painful when trying to support powershell core cross platform where different means of persistence might not be available (like the registry) but may be the best option for some people in their environment (group policy pushing registry keys).

Supporting an infinitely variable means of persisting configuration within each module that is written is the wrong way to handle this but is what is done across many modules today which results in varying levels of compatibility not because the core functionality doesn't work but simply due to how the module persists and retrieves configuration information.

The method of persisting and then loading some arbitrary module configuration should be independent of the module's implementation but to do that I need a way to know when the module is loaded so that I can trigger pulling the appropriate values from whatever the right persistence mechanism is in the particular environment we are in to then configure the module with the appropriate state.

An example of how I thinks this might work is maybe there is a .net event on the runspace object that is triggered when a module is loaded. This might have to be tied to a WMI event that executes each time a PowerShell runspace is instantiated. If we had a PowerShellConfiguration module that knew what modules it had been setup to load configuration into, then the wmi event could trigger the import of the PowerShellConfiguration module which on import would start listening to the .net event for importing modules into the runspace and call the various configuration related Set methods of a module when it sees the module imported.

Comment: Is there any research to suggest any such events exist?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspacepool.statechanged?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#applies-to might be one piece of something that could be leveraged to accomplish this. I haven't read through the classes that I think might have something. I was hopeful that someone else with more experience might already be familiar with the events raise. I feel like I have seen security products that log all powershell executed on a system, including runspaces in other processes, so they must be hooking into something to capture that.